# Import tab-delimited text file and insert to a table in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking to write a VBA code in Microsoft Word that does the following:

- Imports a tab-delimited text file and determines the number of rows in it (columns are fixed at 3)
- Creates a table in the active Word document with the determined number of rows and columns and pastes the content of the text file in the table.

I have written the following snippet so far that reads the text file and creates the table in the active document. But I am at a loss as to how to insert the contents of the file into the table.

```
Dim FileContent As String

Const TextFile As String = "C:\Code\Input.txt"

Const BookmarkName As String = "ProfilesBegin"

Open TextFile For Input As #1
FileContent = Input(LOF(1), #1)
Close #1


' Getting the number of rows in the txt file
Const ForAppending = 8
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set theFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(TextFile, ForAppending, Create:=True)
txtrows = theFile.Line - 1
Set FSO = Nothing

' Inserting table in active document
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="ProfilesBegin"
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Selection.InsertRows txtrows - 1
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I have updated the question as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sub InsertCSV_Tbl()
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set Rng = .Bookmarks("ProfilesBegin")
  With Rng
    .InsertFile FileName:="C:\Code\Input.txt", Range:=.Duplicate, ConfirmConversion:=False, Link:=False
    .ConvertToTable Separator:=vbTab
  End With
End With
End Sub
```